# Chat con socket en java netbeans

Tags: java, servidor, socket, cliente

Buen día.

Tengo este chat cliente/servidor, realizado con sockets.

Funciona bien si lo ejecuto de forma individual cada uno, como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero este chat lo requiero ejecutar desde un Menu Item, cuando realizo el llamado me trae los chats pero no funcionan.

El código que tengo en el llamado a los jframe chat cliente y chat servidor es el siguiente:

```
private void btnClienteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    chats.chat_client cliente = new chats.chat_client();
    cliente.setVisible(true);
    
    chats.chat_server servidor = new chats.chat_server();
    servidor.setVisible(true);
    
}
```

**Código de chat cliente**

```
package chats;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;


public class chat_client extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream dout;
    
    public chat_client() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void msg_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
        try {
            
        String msgout = "";
        msgout = msg_text.getText().trim();
        dout.writeUTF(msgout);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    } 

 public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new chat_client().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        try {
            
            s = new Socket("192.168.1.75",5000);
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            String msgin = "";
            
            while(!msgin.equals("exit")){
                
                msgin = din.readUTF();
                msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\nServer: "+msgin);
                
            }
                    
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea msg_area;
    public javax.swing.JButton msg_send;
    private javax.swing.JTextField msg_text;
    // End of variables declaration                   

}
```

**Código chat servidor**

```
package chats;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class chat_server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    
    static ServerSocket ss;
    static Socket s;
    static DataInputStream din;
    static DataOutputStream dout;
    
   
    
    public chat_server() {
        initComponents();
    }

private void msg_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        try {
         
        String msgout = "";
        msgout = msg_text.getText().trim();
        dout.writeUTF(msgout);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }  

 public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(chat_server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new chat_server().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        
        String msgin = "";
         
        try {
            
            ss  = new ServerSocket(5000);
            s = ss.accept();
            
            din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            
            while (!msgin.equals("exit")){
                msgin = din.readUTF();
                msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\nCliente: "+msgin);
                
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea msg_area;
    public javax.swing.JButton msg_send;
    private javax.swing.JTextField msg_text;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Como mencione en un principio el chat funciona correctamente si se ejecuta fuera del Menu Item, pero cuando lo hago desde el Menu Item no envían ni reciben mensajes.

Espero me puedan ayudar,

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tienes toda tu lógica de conexión al servidor en el método *main*.

El *main* se ejecuta cuando invocas la clase la lanzar la máquina virtual("java chats.chat_server"). Pero cuando invocas al constructor no se ejecuta ese método.

Lo que tienes que hacer es sacar toda la lógica a un método, para que lo invoques tanto desde el *main* como desde el constructor.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta, tienes razón.
Me podrías indicar donde puedo ponerlo? Disculpa pero no soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Lo dicho, crea un método nuevo en tu clase y pon la lógica allí. Si no sabes lo que es un método, deberías estudiar un poco el lenguaje antes de ponerte a tocar el código.